# Error while editing/ reseting customer password

Tags: magento-1.7

When I try to edit customer password through admin - customers magento is giving me error- Invalid transactional email code:

No email template was added or changed on the website.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely a transactional email template in the admin was deleted, or a setting somehow was lost. I've seen it happen.

To fix it, you should just need to reset the value for the customer password change email.

1. Go to: `Admin > System > Configuration > Customer Configuration`
2. Open the `Password Options` section.
3. Make sure both template settings there have valid templates selected.
4. Save.

That should do it. If not, could be related to site customizations. That's more involved to troubleshoot.

Comment: The site use default magenta templates only. i choose them again and saved. But the error keep coming.